# SUM same column twice performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

DBMS: SQL Server 2012 Express

I have an SQL Statement which looks something like this:

```
SELECT

    OverSpeedings = SUM(OverSpeeding),
    OverspeedingPoints = SUM(OverSpeeding) * 5,


FROM
    MyTable

GROUP BY    
        COLUMNS_HERE
```

I was wondering does Adding the same column twice cause an impact on Performance? Meaning does SQL Server add the column twice? Or will it add the column once and use for both columns in the result set?

Or should I use a CTE with one `SUM` like the following:

```
SELECT

    OverSpeedings,
    OverspeedingPoints = OverSpeedings * 5,

FROM
    (
    SELECT

        OverSpeedings = SUM(OverSpeeding)

    FROM
        MyTable

    GROUP BY    
        COLUMNS_HERE    
    ) A
```

Comment: Well, you can test! Fill a sample table with a few million rows and time the 2 queries. And then another with say `SELECT OverSpeedings = SUM(OverSpeeding),    OverspeedingPoints = SUM(OverSpeeding + 0) * 5, ...` which should do the calculation twice

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I did -  The Query time is about the same - so is the Logical Reads, and also the Scan Count

Comment: Also add a tag with the dbms you use (and version). Is it SQL Server or something else?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 - Express

Comment: Is there any difference in the query plan? Is your interest in tuning this query?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik the query plan is the aswell. Yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> was wondering does Adding the same column twice cause an impact on Performance? Meaning does SQL Server add the column twice? Or will it add the column once and use for both columns in the result set?

Sum will be calculated once and result is used for multiple columns referring the same `sum`

Below is sample setup from my instance ,which will prove the same

```
select 
sum(empid) as empidsum,
sum(empid)*2 as empidsum,
sum(empid)*4 as empid4
 from orders
```

execution plan:
[image]

In the above execution plan,highlighted computed scalar shows below

```
Scalar Operator([Expr1003]*(2))  
Scalar Operator([Expr1003]*(4))
```

Where `Expr1003` is the sum calculated by previous compute scalar

> should I use a CTE with one SUM like the following

CTE is just for readability,using a CTE won't help performance .

There are cases where materialzing CTE will help in improving the query.Look out this answer for more details:

[Which are more performant, CTE or temporary tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205087/2975396)

Comment: +1 for CTE info. It's easy to forget that the optimizer decomposes the CTE before executing. It can help the human query writer but it means nothing to execution engine.